# Looking to transition to a new role that lets me work remotely, but the position is a lower rate

Tags: salary, telecommute, relocation

My situation is a bit complex. Because my wife has moved to another state for her work, I want to be able to join her, but I don't want to leave my current employer. I've requested the ability to work remotely 100% so I can move to be with her. My employers have found a new role that can be done entirely remotely within the program I'm working on and rather than have me leave the program or worse, the company, they'll help me out by making this transition happen. I'm very grateful for their willingness to do this.

However, the new role is funded at about 20% less than I'm currently making. I really don't want to cut my income down, especially since my current financial circumstances are not great, due to maintaining two residences, and double bills between my wife and I.

My boss and his boss have met with me and told me to come back to them after considering the situation. They say that the closer to that 20% cut I can accept, the faster and easier it will be to get the switch approved and make it happen. My financial situation is one where we'll be in very bad position by spring as long as we're maintaining two homes. But too much paycut will make it harder to afford the work on our current home that will be needed to sell it.

I'm not required to accept the 20% and might come back with something else, but the less cut I can accept, the harder it will be to get me approved to move roles and be free to work remote. My market value will not go down because of this role switch, even if my income does, so I'd be highly under-paid for my qualifications if I accept a cut. Frankly, I'm not sure why the role rate matters, I'm already making what I'm making out of the same budget. My desire is to insist on not having my pay cut. Who wants to lose 20% of their income? Should I push to not take a cut in my income, or cooperate and accept the 20% cut or some lesser cut?

Comment: I understand that you have a tough decision to make, but do note that you are asking an advice and answers will be mostly opinion-based. Nevertheless, as @JoeStrazzere mentioned, if your salary will be too low to sustain your financial situation when you work 100% remote on your current company, it's better to look for better opportunities on the same location as your wife.

Comment: Is there no saving in commuting cost or time that working at home would provide?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to attack this rationally, by going through a bunch of items to consider

1. Is the work you will do the same, or does it have different scope or impact ?
2. Will working remotely make you less or more efficient? You will be missing valuable face to face communication, on the other hand you will spent less time with water cooler talk and meetings.
3. How good are you at self managing? Will your productivity be higher or lower?
4. Do you need to occasionally travel back to the mother-ship? If yes, who pays for the travel?
5. How will you manage IT and facility support? Does stuff need to be shipped back and forth? What happens if your company PC doesn't boot in the morning?

Go through the list first in your head and than discuss it with your managers. You can make data based arguments on where working remotely is a benefit for the company and where it's not. Balance the two against each other and try to make a fair suggestions what you feel that should amount to.

It's pretty normal that remote employees get paid somewhat less: you save commuting cost and time and communication is less effective and harder. Often the productivity & impact is as quite as high as for in-office employees. It also limits the scope of work you can do, not all projects are suitable for remote work.

Keep your own financial needs out of the discussion with the manager. What's happening with your house is your concern, not theirs.

Comment: Did you mean to say “impact is /not/ as quite as high”, as there appears to be a missing “not”?